# Yii implement multiple form validation on single view

Tags: validation, yii

I want implement user profile update same as implemented in [Facebook setting](https://www.facebook.com/settings).
the same show/hide forms.

I have a section of profile image upload also so i do't want to apply ajax forms.
I tried it in three different ways.

1. One single action and multiple form submit to that.
   **Problem**:- Model validation -> have to set blank model variable to all other model except the  submitted one
   and how to show/hide forms
2. Multiple form and submit each one by ajax.
   **Problem**:- Image upload
3. Tabs 
   **Problem** :- don't know how validation will work.

Can anyone have a better solution?

Comment: I thing that what do you want to is to use **scenarios**, have a look in these links:

[link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

[link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19410-scenario-explanation/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, better architectural solution is a 2, A workaround for image upload: Upload images asynchronously, after upload, extract from response imageId value and add to hidden field in the main form.